# Rav Moshe Feinstein and showers in the nine days

Tags: health-safety-shmira, nine-days, moshe-feinstein, showering-bathing

Someone who I would consider reliable enough to be worth checking told me that Rav Moshe Feinstein would send a message to summer camps to ensure that the campers were showering during the 9 days because of health issues.

Is there any known corroboration for that? Either something he wrote, or any other recollection of such guidance from him?

Comment: Well here is his own writing http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&pgnum=149

Comment: @sam, sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Yishai - not exactly. The text says that he allowed bathing to get rid of sweat, and only on a "hot day" (I don't know what that means according to that text.) Offhand, it seems that he essentially reiterated what is already stated in SA.

Comment: @danf where in the Shulchan Aruch

Comment: @Yishai, also, that was a letter to a Rabbi Lamner(?), not to camps (plural).

Answer (score 2):

R. Feinstein briefly discussed showering during the Nine Days in a responsum:

**[Igrot Moshe E.H. 4:84:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&pgnum=149)**

> ולגבי שאלת בני הישיבה אם ביום חום מותר לרחוץ אחר ר"ח אב עד עת"ב מאחר שמכונים להסיר הזיעה ולא מחמת תענוג באמת יש להקל
>
> And regarding the question of the members of the *yeshivah* if it is permissible to bathe on a hot day between Rosh Chodesh Av and Tisha B'av, since their intention is to remove the sweat rather than for pleasure, in truth one can be lenient.

It is thus conceivable from a halachic standpoint that he would have sent such a message
to summer camps.